# Continuous function on colimit

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, limits-and-colimits, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.  Suppose that $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a strictly nested sequence of sub-Banach spaces, for which $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n$ dense in $X$.  Then the colimit is an LF-space which is not metrizable.

Since $f|_{X_n}$ is continuous to $\mathbb{R}$, then by the universal property of the colimit *(in the category LCS of locally convex spaces and continuous linear maps)* it should extend to $f':X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (where not $X$ is considered with the colimit topology and not its original Banach space topology).

What is $f'$ (explicitly in tems of $f|_{X_n}$)?  My intuition is that it is either $f$ or an infinite-sum of the $f|_{X_n}$..

**Note:** In particular it shouldn't be $f$ because the colimit topology is strictly finer.

Comment: Do you mean that $\bigcup_n X_n$ is **dense in $X$** or **equal to $X$**? I think the latter scenario is ruled out (assuming the $X_n$ are strictly increasing) by a Baire category argument

Comment: Also, colimit in what category?

Comment: Yes, I oversimplified things.  Dense and also in the category LCS (with continuous linear maps as morphisms).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *$X$ is considered with the colimit topology*: Only $Y=\bigcup_n X_n$ has a colimit topology and (as Yemon mentions) $Y$ is hardly ever equal to $X$. And I don't see how density of $Y$ in $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ should help --  this does not mean that $X$ is a completion of $Y$ (which need not be complete but easily can be, e.g., is all $X_n$ are closed subspaces of $X$ or if all $X_n$ are reflexive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand fully your setting (for example, are the $X_n$ given the topology of a subspace or simply the embedding map $X_n \to X$ is required to be continuous... Or is $f$ linear... etc.). But the colimit topology on $X$ will be finer than the original topology on $X$, and therefore the functional $f$, being continuous w.r.t. the original topology will also be continuous w.r.t. the colimit topology, and hence it satisfies the demand of the universal property - the unique continuous map from the colimit whose restrictions to the $X_n$'s are the given... So yes, I think $f^{\prime}$ will be equal to the original $f$.